# Needs to Redirect all URLS matching a pattern to another url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have migrated my site from old server to new server so there is a change in urls structures. So currently when the site loads some of the blog post are in the old url

Example

This is my current URLS , indexed on Search Engines and other sites,

https://www.example.com/blogs/2019/07/11/page-tile/

I need this url to change to https://www.example.com/blog/2019/07/11/page-tile/

Same for all urls matching the /blogs to /blog without missing any further url structure using .htaccess file

Comment: please show your attempted code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this,

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^blogs/.*$ blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```